# JUnit Parameterized Tests Display Newline

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

It's a known bug that JUnit's [Parameterized Tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) will silently fail if you attempt to display a newline character: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474465

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Example {

    private String actual;
    private String expected;

    public Example(String actual, String expected) {
        this.actual = actual;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Parameters(name = "{0}") // can't do this ("\n" not allowed)
    public static Collection<Object[]> testCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { "Hello\nWorld", "Hello\nWorld" }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Are there any known workarounds around this problem? For example, is there a way to replace the newline character here: `@Parameters(name = "{0}")`, but not actually in the test itself?

Comment: try double-escaping the slash? like `\\n`

Comment: I've wasted an hour trying to figure out what was wrong, and you solved my problem in about a minute... thanks :)

Comment: It's called "I have ran into the same issue before" (aka experience) - Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-escape the slash, like `\\n`